# MySQL data - Count number of phone calls at the same time

Tags: php, mysql

I have a MySQL table with phone calls. Every row means one phone call.
Columns are:

```
start_time
start_date
duration
```

I need to get a maximum phone calls called at the same time. It's because of telephone exchange dimensioning.

My solution is to create two timestamp columns `timestamp_start` and `timestamp_end`. Then I run a loop *second by second, day by day* and ask MySQL something like:

```
SELECT Count(*) FROM tbl WHERE start_date IN (thisday, secondday) AND "this_second_checking" BETWEEN timestamp_start AND timestamp_end;
```

It's quite slow.
Is there a better solution? Thank you!

EDIT - I use this solution and it gives me proper results. There is used SQL layer dibi - http://dibiphp.com/cs/quick-start .

```
$starts = dibi::query("SELECT ts_start, ts_end FROM " . $tblname . " GROUP BY ts_start");
if(count($starts) > 0):
  foreach ($starts as $row) {
    if(isset($result)) unset($result);
    $result = dibi::query('SELECT Count(*) FROM ' . $tblname . ' WHERE "'.$row->ts_start.'" BETWEEN ts_start AND ts_end');
    $num = $result->fetchSingle();
    if($total_max < $num):
      $total_max = $num;
    endif;    
  }  
endif;
echo "Total MAX: " . $total_max;
```

Comment: you only need to check when a new call is started for how many are running, no need to check every second

Comment: Have you got indexes on start_date, timestamp_start and timestamp_end?

Comment: Yes, I have indexes. It was a huge improvement.
Blem: I think it over, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Instead of running it second by second, you should for each row (phonecall) see what other phone calls were active at that time. After that you group all of the results by the row's ID, and check which has the maximum count. So basically something like this:

```
SELECT MAX(calls.count)
FROM (
    SELECT a.id, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM tbl AS a
    INNER JOIN tbl AS b ON (
        (b.timestamp_start BETWEEN a.timestamp_start AND a.timestamp_end)
        OR
        (b.timestamp_end BETWEEN a.timestamp_start AND a.timestamp_end)
    )
    GROUP BY a.id
) AS calls
```

Creating an index on the timestamp columns will help as well.

Comment: You are a bit faster then me :) +1

Comment: This doesn't give me the same results, as my first algorithm. Maybe I've got there some error in my program. I review this in next 3 hours.

Comment: The timestamps include the date part, not just the time, right? If not, they should, that way you don't need to separately check for date _and_ time columns.

Comment: Right. Timestamps are created from start_time+start_date (start) and duration (end).

Comment: reko_t: Thank you for your first sentence! :) My solution is in the first post (edited).

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to add something to @reko_t answer. I think there is a use case to consider.

Calls that start before and ended after - Calls completely overlapped

So, how about:

```
SELECT MAX(calls.count)
FROM (
    SELECT a.id, COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM tbl AS a
    INNER JOIN tbl AS b ON (
        (b.timestamp_start BETWEEN a.timestamp_start AND a.timestamp_end)
        OR
        (b.timestamp_end BETWEEN a.timestamp_start AND a.timestamp_end)
        OR
        (b.timestamp_start <= a.timestamp_start AND b.timestamp_end >= a.timestamp_end)
    )
    GROUP BY a.id
) AS calls
```

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
SELECT MAX(callCount) FROM (SELECT COUNT(duration) AS callCount, CONCAT(start_date,start_time) AS callTime FROM tbl GROUP BY callTime)
```

That would give you the max number of calls in a single "time".  Assuming start_date and start_time are strings.  If they're integer times, you could probably optimise it somewhat.

Comment: `CONCAT(start_date,start_time) AS callTime FROM tbl GROUP BY callTime` - `That would give you the max number of calls in a single "time".` - Really? o_O Concat'ing dates and grouping by concat result make no sense to me for the purpose of solving this issue...

Comment: It would group all identical times together, however I see your point now - it doesn't do overlapping time durations, only simultaneously started times.  Apologies.